# Magento - Catalog Price Rules

Tags: magento

When I selecting a one category (in Rule conditions) everything works, but if I choose more categories (in Rule conditions) in the database does not record anything, but in my admin panel it appears that everything is ok.

Magento ver. 1.4.0.1

Comment: Post a screenshot of your conditions.